# How does ICA works with more than two sources

Tags: eeg, ica

In all tutorials on ICA that i've seen, two sources are separated from each other.
but how is two source separation different from multi-source separations like data recorded by EEG hats ?

Comment: well, you've seen tutorials that only work on two sources then - but nothing about the ICA is inherently limited to that. Maybe a textbook would be the next step to go a bit more solid.

Comment: I needed to have a general understanding of ICA for my thesis about EEG data analysis. in reality work is done by MNE framework and the whole process is seen as a black box. do you know any online not too deep resource to answer my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider [this book](http://pzs.dstu.dp.ua/DataMining/ica/bibl/Stone.pdf), it builds up ICA from the basics. It even has a description and some references to papers that tackled EEG data with ICA.